# How do I make a Google Fusion Table map which allows users to select multiple maps?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm a JavaScript newbie who has started using Google Fusion Tables, and I was wondering if any experts on those two things could help me out with something.

Here are four maps I made from one Fusion Table (they're embed codes):

```
<iframe width="800" height="600" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=MAP&amp;q=select+col4%3E%3E1+from+13A1jVfCkkhx7UORDIVPxKdHkDTks3_2X_9hFprs&amp;h=false&amp;lat=38&amp;lng=-98&amp;z=4&amp;t=1&amp;l=col4%3E%3E1&amp;y=2&amp;tmplt=2"></iframe>
<br><br>
<iframe width="800" height="600" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=MAP&amp;q=select+col4%3E%3E1+from+13A1jVfCkkhx7UORDIVPxKdHkDTks3_2X_9hFprs&amp;h=false&amp;lat=38&amp;lng=-98&amp;z=4&amp;t=1&amp;l=col4%3E%3E1&amp;y=3&amp;tmplt=3"></iframe>
<br><br>
<iframe width="800" height="600" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=MAP&amp;q=select+col4%3E%3E1+from+13A1jVfCkkhx7UORDIVPxKdHkDTks3_2X_9hFprs&amp;h=false&amp;lat=38&amp;lng=-98&amp;z=4&amp;t=1&amp;l=col4%3E%3E1&amp;y=4&amp;tmplt=4"></iframe>
<br><br>
<iframe width="800" height="600" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=MAP&amp;q=select+col4%3E%3E1+from+13A1jVfCkkhx7UORDIVPxKdHkDTks3_2X_9hFprs&amp;h=false&amp;lat=38&amp;lng=-98&amp;z=4&amp;t=1&amp;l=col4%3E%3E1&amp;y=5&amp;tmplt=5"></iframe>
```

I'd like to make a map which has a dropdown with each of these maps as an option. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here's a sort of example: The Texas Tribune has [a Fusion Table map](http://www.texastribune.org/library/data/redistricting-viewer/) with a dropdown in the upper left which lets users select four different maps (state house districts, state senate districts, etc.).

I looked at the source code, but I think I'm still a bit unfamiliar with the Fusion Tables API.

If anyone knows how I can figure this out, I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Fusion Tables so I need more information. I noticed the difference between each iframe is y=2 and tmplt=2 becoming 3, 4, and 5. What exactly does that mean? How are you re-coloring the map? Is it different data? The query looks the same. I'm trying to find an equivalent in the Javascript API.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I don't think that you need 4 different maps, but you rather want to show different data on the same map (like the Texas Tribune example). Check out [this simple example](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_query) to get the basic idea.

Comment: @Lilina: It seems like 'tmplt' refers to template -- that is, 'tmplt=1' is one map with its own colors and data, while 'tmplt=2' is another map with different colors and data, and so on. A Fusion Tables file is on GoogleDocs (a cloud-like system), and is set up to look like a database (e.g., any spreadsheet software). In the latest version of Fusion Tables, you can make several different maps in the same file, and that's why 'tmplt' and 'y' are different. Each have different colors and data displays. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Odi: I'm reading your link now, and I'll let you know if I've got more questions after I'm done.

Comment: @Odi: Thanks for the link. I'm following that example with another map I made, but my dropdown doesn't seem to work. The code I wrote is mostly a copy-paste of Google's code, and I've uploaded them to the Fusion Table discussion group, in case you'd like to look at it. [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/fusion-tables-users-group/FVQLZqWx188)

Answer (score 0):

I would have four Fusion tables/maps and use the code on your web page to show only the one that is selected from the dropdown. It's a job for your Javascript, not Fusion. I have something similar in which users can select (by GET link) which map is displayed. It's all in PHP, though.